# django/mod_wsgi unable to import module (which is in a directory on the python path)

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I am running django with mod_wsgi/apache and receive this ImportError:

```
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.2.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named adspygoogle.dfp.DfpClient
```

This module is inside my django `app/libs` directory, which is included in the python path.

Strangely, when using `./manage.py shell` or `./manage.py runserver` with `pdb.set_trace()`, dropping into the debugger just before the import, I am able to import the module without any problems.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the `libs/adspygoogle` directory had somehow become dirty in a way that git hadn't tracked. I replaced it with a fresh checkout and it now works...

I still can't explain why I could import it in the shell or with runserver.

Answer (score 0):

Set the python path for the wsgi process.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath

Comment: I'm using daemon mode, so I added the python-path as follows:
`WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

No luck unfortunately.